# calendar adding of event using fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, html, calendar

[DEMO](http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.4.0/demos/selectable.html)

I am doing the fullcalendar and i was able to create it properly the demo above is exactly like what i have done so far. I wanted to add new function on the calendar on the demo if you add event and refresh the page the added event is gone. I wanted to save the event into the database so that if you refresh it it will still be there and also i can delete old events.
The default events are added like

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            defaultDate: '2015-02-12',
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            select: function(start, end) {
                var title = prompt('Event Title:');
                var eventData;
                if (title) {
                    eventData = {
                        title: title,
                        start: start,
                        end: end
                    };
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true); // stick? = true
                }
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
            },
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            events: [
                {
                    title: 'All Day Event',
                    start: '2015-02-01'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Long Event',
                    start: '2015-02-07',
                    end: '2015-02-10'
                },
                {
                    id: 999,
                    title: 'Repeating Event',
                    start: '2015-02-09T16:00:00'
                },
                {
                    id: 999,
                    title: 'Repeating Event',
                    start: '2015-02-16T16:00:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Conference',
                    start: '2015-02-11',
                    end: '2015-02-13'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Meeting',
                    start: '2015-02-12T10:30:00',
                    end: '2015-02-12T12:30:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Lunch',
                    start: '2015-02-12T12:00:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Meeting',
                    start: '2015-02-12T14:30:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Happy Hour',
                    start: '2015-02-12T17:30:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Dinner',
                    start: '2015-02-12T20:00:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Birthday Party',
                    start: '2015-02-13T07:00:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Click for Google',
                    url: 'http://google.com/',
                    start: '2015-02-28'
                }
            ]
        });

    });
```

I want to be able to capture the data in the alert box when a date is clicked but i cant find where it is located.
I need to capture the text from that alert box so that i can store it in database after clicking ok.

Im still trying to read the documentation to find where i can get the text and store it in database
The Documentation is found [here](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select: function(start, end) {
    var title = prompt('Event Title:');
    var eventData;
    if (title) {
        eventData = {
            title: title,
            start: start,
            end: end
        };
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true); // stick? = true
    }
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
}
```

This is the part where the text is being get the variable title is the data from the alert which will be the title of the event.